# Hibernate's session factory and no recognizing identifier

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, mapping

I'm getting an hibernate's error that is quite strange. I've mapped all the entities in my  MySQL database thank to the hibernate code generation, I've set up all the relationships and everything seemed to work, but now I'm getting this error

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.YouDroop.Data.Entities.Showcase
at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:243)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1373)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.buildMappings(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:160)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$4.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:272)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:108)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildMappings(ConsoleConfiguration.java:270)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.java:44)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:98)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:232)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

where the entity Showcase is this one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "showcase", schema = "youdroopnorelationships")
public class Showcase implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int code;
private Function function;
private String description;
private int capacity;
private int currentNumberOfProducts;

public Showcase() {
}

public Showcase(int code, Function function, int capacity, int currentNumberOfProducts) {
    this.code = code;
    this.function = function;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.currentNumberOfProducts = currentNumberOfProducts;
}

public Showcase(int code, Function function, String description, int capacity, int currentNumberOfProducts) {
    this.code = code;
    this.function = function;
    this.description = description;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.currentNumberOfProducts = currentNumberOfProducts;
}

@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Code", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "Function_Name", nullable = false)
public Function getFunction() {
    return this.function;
}

public void setFunction(Function function) {
    this.function = function;
}

@Column(name = "Description", length = 100)
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Column(name = "Capacity", nullable = false)
public int getCapacity() {
    return this.capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

@Column(name = "CurrentNumberOfProducts", nullable = false)
public int getCurrentNumberOfProducts() {
    return this.currentNumberOfProducts;
}

public void setCurrentNumberOfProducts(int currentNumberOfProducts) {
    this.currentNumberOfProducts = currentNumberOfProducts;
}

}
```

As you can see I've written all the annotations in the right place, even the @Id one, and also che .hbm file reflects it.
When I rebuild the Hibernate configuration the error comes out, while if I only refresh it, it works but doesn't allow me to see the Session Factory, due to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have the right imports:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

and not

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

hope this works

Comment: I'm using this imports:        

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.*;

Comment: can you show me the code of your database table so maybe i could help?

Comment: the database table is below, it's called Showcase